# What should I notice for the USB stick use as installer?

Tags: usb, system-installation, dd, usb-drive, storage

I have a few questions about the USB stick used as an installer in Linux.

---

#### 1) Should I leave extra space after running `dd`?

So for Windows user, you might be familiar with [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/), with rufus you can burn .iso file to USB sticks. For safety I personally prefer using `dd` method which is a common way we burn .iso file in Linux, and here's the question. Since I haven't used `dd` in Linux yet, I don't know how it results in Linux, but as I use rufus on Windows, it actually erase all and creates a new partition for `dd`, and which in my case (I'm using [solus](https://solus-project.com/home/)) is `30MB`. Then with this result, I'm wondering, if I use `dd` to burn iso and it only uses `30MB`, does it meant we can use a USB stick like 2GB or even small as 64MB to install the installer?

---

#### 2) Will use `USB 2` or `USB 3` as installer makes any difference?

So we know the installer will install different types of Linux depending on the hardware or BIOS (for example legacy V.S. EFI). Then will use USB 2 or USB 3 as installer makes any difference? Except for the installation speed.

---

#### 3) Can I reuse the installer?

Last question, if I used the installer for a installation process, can I use it in another installation for another disk? Or I should format and reburn a new one just in case something is damaged during the previous installation process?

Comment: related to Debian: https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb

Comment: @Fabian how about the storage?

Comment: "if I use dd to burn iso and it only uses 30MB, does it meant we can use a USB stick like 2GB" yes you can, for details (Debian related) please read https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.html.en ([Installation Guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/installmanual))